# Does the placement of keys on a keyboard have any special kind of name or code?

Tags: keyboard

I'm looking for a new keyboard for my PC. When it comes to keyboards, I'm very picky about the lay-out. I highly prefer a QUERTY-keyboard with the right-most column to look like this:

```
    |<--|
  |] | \|
    |ENT|
  |shift|
 |fn|ctl|
```

Currently I have a keyboard with a 'vertical' enter, moving the `\` to behind the `"`. also the 3x2 Insert/Home... buttons are down one row, with Pause/break and Scroll Lock above it. It's hideous!

While looking for new keyboards, I mostly come across keyboards like this one, and I can't see the forest for all the trees...

Is there a special name or code or whatever I can look at to find the key placement I want?

Comment: [Some info on this](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Return_key)

Comment: What you're looking for is called language configuration. Although I'm not familiar with keyboards with an fn key on the right, the rest should be `Qwerty us-int` layout.